# How can I stop regretting about the mishappening in the world?

Tags: life, living

I am a student whose duty is to study but it worries me that I cannot contribute to betterment of world or society.
**Do our Hindu scriptures says anything about our duty towards world or society? Or how we are supposed to contribute towards betterment of it?**

Comment: Here questions should be about Hinduism only. You need to make your question Hinduism specific which isn't the case right now :-)

Comment: @Rickross You are back... Welcome...

Comment: Haha thanks again .. last time it was you too who welcomed me. But I actually was active since last 20 days or more. So I did not resume activity from today. But its not your fault as now we can't check who is active and who is not @hanugm

Comment: I think commentary on how to handle miseries around the world may help @ayush?

Comment: I recommend you to read Shanthi parva from Mahabharatha.

Comment: Swami Vivekand mentions that Morality is the only thing which pushes us towards other living beings and this nature. This morality is present inside us by default due to presence of Aatman but in a poorly developed state. This needs to be properly developed which can be done by extensive reading of Shastras. The more you read, the better your morality and understanding towards the world.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Hindu shastra does talk about our duty towards others. If you see someone wasting his life then you should urge him to mend his ways. That is all you have to do and in practical point of view can do. If he doesn't mend his ways then there is nothing more you can do. Remember that everyone has karmic history and so acts according to their karma. All you can do is to serve others to the best of your ability.

Liberality

> 1. THE Gods have not ordained hunger to be our death: even to the well-fed man comes death in varied shape. The riches of the liberal
>    never waste away, while he who will not give finds none to comfort
>    him. 2 **The man with food in store who, when the needy comes in
>    miserable case begging for bread to eat, Hardens his heart against
>    him-even when of old he did him service-finds not one to comfort him.
>    3 Bounteous is he who gives unto the beggar who comes to him in want
>    of food and feeble.** Success attends him in the shout of battle. He
>    makes a friend of him in future troubles. 4 No friend is he who to his
>    friend and comrade who comes imploring food, will offer nothing. Let
>    him depart-no home is that to rest in-, and rather seek a stranger to
>    support him. 5 Let the rich satisfy the poor implorer, and bend his
>    eye upon a longer pathway. Riches come now to one, now to another, and
>    like the wheels of cars are ever rolling. 6 The foolish man wins food
>    with fruitless labour: that food -I speak the truth- shall be his
>    ruin. He feeds no trusty friend, no man to love him. All guilt is he
>    who eats with no partaker. 7 The ploughshare ploughing makes the food
>    that feeds us, and with its feet cuts through the path it follows.
>    Better the speaking than the silent Brahman: the liberal friend out
>    yalues him who gives not. 8 He with one foot hath far outrun the
>    biped, and the two-footed catches the three-footed. Four-footed
>    creatures come when bipeds call them, and stand and look where five
>    are met together. 9 The hands are both alike: their labour differs.
>    The yield of sister milch-kine is unequal. Twins even differ in their
>    strength and vigour: two, even kinsmen, differ in their bounty.

**Rig Veda 10.117**

**Helping the indigent**

> Bhishma said, "**Whatever wishes one entertains with respect to
> oneself, one should certainly cherish with respect to another. With
> the surplus wealth one may happen to own one should relieve the wants
> of the indigent.** It is for this reason that the Creator ordained the
> practice of increasing one's wealth (by trade or laying it out at
> interest)."

**Mahabharata, Santi Parva, Section CCLIX**

All spiritual practices are in vain if you close your eyes to suffering of others.

> I abide in all beings as their inner-most soul. Disregarding My
> presence within them, men make a show of worshiping Me through images.
> **If one disregards Me present in all as their soul and Lord but
> ignorantly offers worship only to images, such worship is as
> ineffective as a sacrificial offering made in ashes. A man who
> persecutes Me residing in others, who is proud and haughty, who looks
> upon God as the other – such a person will never attain to peace of
> mind. If a man disregards and persecutes fellow beings, but worships
> Me in images with numerous rituals and rich offerings, I am not at all
> pleased with him for proffering such worship. A man should, however,
> worship Me in images, side by side with discharging his duties, which
> include the love of all beings, until he actually realises My presence
> in in himself and in all beings. As long as man is self-centred and
> makes an absolute distinction between himself and others (without
> recognising the unity of all in Me, the Inner Pervader), he will be
> subject to the great fear of Death (including every form of
> deprivation of self-interest). So overcoming the separateness of a
> self-centred life, one should serve all beings with gifts, honour and
> love, recognising that such service is really being rendered to Me** who
> reside in all beings as their innermost soul.

**Srimad Bhagavata Purana III.29.21-27**

Comment: No no I meant that assume someone 500km away from me is abusing alcohol and is wasting money of his family . It's like nothing I can do about it. But I dont know why I keep regretting I can't do anything about it which distracts me from my study

Comment: Forget what you can't do. Do what you can do. Remember that everyone has his own karmic history and so all you can do is to give him good advice. If he doesn't mend his ways then there is nothing further you can do.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is given in [Yoga Sutras](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-sutras-with-vedanta-commentaries/d/doc115502.html)

> क्लेशमूलः कर्माशयो दृष्टादृष्टजन्मवेदनीयः ॥१२॥
>
> A man's latent tendencies have been **created by his past thoughts and
> actions.** These tendencies will bear fruits, both in this life and in
> lives to come.

A man who is facing problems in his life is because of his past life karmas. So if you are feeling bad for not being able to help someone, you shouldn't because it was not in his prarabdha to receive help from someone.

Comment: This is like saying that a mother shouldn't love her blind son, because he was born blind due to his ill prarabdha karma. Vivekananda was right in pointing out that "Bhakti alone, without service towards others, is sentimental nonsense which makes one impotent".

Comment: @learner a mother loves her child despite of his disabilities. Your question doesn't make any sense. The child is already suffering the deeds of his prarabdha and you can't punish someone for a crime twice.

Comment: "A man who is facing problems in his life is because of his past life karmas. So if you are feeling bad for not being able to help someone, you shouldn't because it was not in his prarabdha to receive help from someone". So you are saying that if anyone is suffering due to his/her prarabdha, you shouldn't help that person?

Comment: @learner we should try to help him but my point is that if we are not able to him it means it is not in his prarabdha to receive help from someone. If it is in his prarabdha he will definitely come out of the trouble. We should try to help everyone but if we can't, it means it is not in his prarabdha.